# Alternative function for php deprecated sql_regcase()

Tags: php, posix, deprecated, pcre, alternate

i have the code bellow:

```
foreach($filetypes as $filetype)
{
  $filenum = $filenum + count(glob($root.$tree.$branch.sql_regcase($filetype),GLOB_NOSORT));
}
```

Function sql_regcase() is deprecated. Does anyone know an alternative for `sql_regcase()` ?
I have tried this below but i think it's not the same.

```
$filenum = $filenum+count(glob($root.$tree.$branch.preg_mach("/$filetype/ig"),GLOB_NOSORT));
```

Also according to this http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php there is No equivalent function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i made it:

```
function my_Sql_regcase($str){

    $res = "";

    $chars = str_split($str);
    foreach($chars as $char){
        if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $char))
            $res .= "[".mb_strtoupper($char, 'UTF-8').mb_strtolower($char, 'UTF-8')."]";
        else
            $res .= $char;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to contact you.  I have used this code snippet to implement case-insensitive image searches within OpenCart.  Although I have not yet submitted the modification to the general community, I wanted to let you know I credited you (ioaniatr) within the comment section.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use case-insensitive flag (`i`) in your regex instead `/[a-z]/i`

Comment: `preg_mach()` is not an alternative in that way that i'm using it. You see, `preg_match()` return's true/false. In the other hand, `sql_regcase()` if `$filetype = 'jPeG';` will create a pattern like: `[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]`. So, the full pattern in `glob()` function would be: `/root/my_site/public_html/images/[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]` and `glob()` will match and return every `jpeg` filenames (case insensitive) in the folder. Then count() will do the math and return the number of the files (jpeg). I don't know how to create the pattern from `$filetype` with another way.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but how about something like that?

```
function sql_regcase($field) {
    $field = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/i", "", $field);
    $field = str_replace("_", "\_", $field);
    $field = str_replace("%", "\%", $field);
    return $field;
}
```